# Calculating mean over an array of lists in R

Tags: arrays, r, list

I have an array built to accept the outputs of a modelling package:

```
M <- array(list(NULL), c(trials,3))
```

Where trials is a number that will generate circa 50 sets of data.
From a sampling loop, I am inserting a specific aspect of the outputs. The output from the modelling package looks a little like this:

```
Mt$effects

c_name    effect        Other
1  DPC_I  0.0818277549  0
2  DPR_I  0.0150814475  0
3  DPA_I  0.0405341027  0
4  DR_I   0.1255416311  0   
5  (etc.)
```

And I am inserting it into my array via a loop

```
For(x in 1:trials) {
    Mt<-run_model(params)
    M[[x,3]] <- Mt$effects
}
```

The object now looks as follows

```
M[,3]
[[1]]
  c_name  effect        Other
1  DPC_I  0.0818277549  0
2  DPR_I  0.0150814475  0
3  DPA_I  0.0405341027  0
4  DR_I   0.1255416311  0   
5  (etc.)

[[2]]
  c_name  effect        Other
1  DPC_I  0.0717384637  0
2  DPR_I  0.0190812375  0
3  DPA_I  0.0856456427  0
4  DR_I   0.2330002551  0   
5  (etc.)

[[3]]
And so on (up to 50 elements).
```

What I want to do is calculate an average (and sd) of effect, grouped by each c_name, across each of these 50 trial runs, but I’m unable to extract the data in to a single dataframe (for example) so that I can run a ddply summarise across them.

I have tried various combinations of rbind, cbind, unlist, but I just can’t understand how to correctly lift this data out of the sequential elements. I note also that any reference to .names results in NULL. 
Any solution would be most appreciated!

Comment: maybe check out [broom package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html)

Comment: You may try `rbindlist` from package `data.table`, it will rbind all df in the list itslef/

Comment: with `data.table` Something along the line `DT <- rbindlist(M[,3]); DT[,list(average=avg(effect),effect.sd=sd(effect)),by=c_name]` should do (untested code, add a `dput(head(M[,3],5))` to your question so we can reproduce the datas easily if you want verified code.

Comment: Hi Tensibai - that worked perfectly, thanks (replacing avg with mean). I'd mark it as answered but there's no flag option!